# Here Map API, map rendering fails

Tags: here-api

Ive successfully created a map, marker and infobubble that uses values from reverse geocoding method. With 1 location, the map works fine and displays the marker and info bubble accordingly. However when i pass two location values from the backend (i am using jsp) the map does not render. [image: image of map when i use two location latitudes and longitudes]

Functions I use are: `addMarkerToGroup`, `addInfoBubble`, `onSuccess`,

```
function addMarkerToGroup(group, position, inf){
var marker = new H.map.Marker(position);
//add custom data to marker
marker.setData(inf);
group.addObject(marker);
}

function addInfoBubble(position,inf){

var group = set_map.group;
var map = set_map.map;
var ui = set_map.ui;

map.addObject(group);

//add 'tap' event listener, that opens info bubble, to the group
group.addEventListener('tap', function(evt){
    //event target is the marker itself, group is a parent event target
    var bubble = new H.ui.InfoBubble(evt.target.getPosition(),{
        // read custom data
        content: evt.target.getData()
    });
      //show info bubble
      ui.addBubble(bubble);
}, false);
addMarkerToGroup(group,position,inf);
    }

function callback(){
    var platform = new H.service.Platform({
    app_id: '#',
    app_code: '#',
    useCIT: true,
   useHTTPS: true
   });

   var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

   var obj = your_location.map_obj;

   var map = new H.Map(
    obj,
   defaultLayers.normal.map,
   {
       zoom:your_location.map_zoom,
       center: {lat:your_location.latitude,lng:your_location.longitude}
   });
  var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

  var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

  var group = new H.map.Group();
}



function onSuccess(result){
var index = your.count;

var myclt = your.get_yours(index);
var myttl = your.get_title(index);
var myinf = your.get_info(index);

var location = result.Response.View[0].Result[0];
var countryName, countryCode, province, city, zipcode;
countryName = location.Location.Address.Country;
countryCode = location.Location.Address.Country;
province = location.Location.Address.State;
zipcode = location.Location.Address.PostalCode;
city = location.Location.Address.City;

               var address = "";
            if (city && city != "") {
                address = city;
            }

            if (province && province != "") {
                if (address && address != "") {
                    address += ", " + province;
                } else {
                    address = province;
                }
            }

            if (zipcode && zipcode != "") {
                if (address && address != "") {
                    address += ", " + zipcode;
                } else {
                    address = zipcode;
                }
            }

            if (countryName && countryName != "") {
                if (address && address != "") {
                    address += ", " + countryName;
                } else {
                    address = countryName;
                }
            }

            $.ajax({
                url:       "view_remote_device_control.do",
                data:      { 
                    mode:      "update",
                    client_id: myclt,
                    city:      city,
                    province:  province,
                    zipcode:   zipcode,
                    country:   countryCode
                },
                type:      "GET",
                cache:     false,
                async:     true
            });

            myttl += address;





var position =  new    H.geo.Point(location.Location.DisplayPosition.Latitude,location.Location.DisplayPosition.Longitude);

var inf  = {content: location.Location.Address.Label};


var myinfo = inf.content;


addInfoBubble(here_maps_callback.map,position,inf.content,here_maps_callback.ui);
return myinf;

};
```

While debugging I get the error:

Uncaught InvalidArgumentError: H.map.ViewModel#setCameraData (Argument #0 position)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so i realized that it the reason why it was not rendering was due to:

```
center: {lat:your_location.latitude,lng:your_location.longitude}
```

Basically due to passing two location values, the location array had two values for both latitude and longitude and it did not know which to use to set the center. By changing both the values of lat and lng to 0 and using:

```
map.setCenter(evt.target.getPosition());
```

inside the group event listener it rendered the map accordingly.

Hope this is helpful

Comment: Glad to hear you figured out the bug. This is very useful information to know, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A bit confused how is the callback is happening, where are the two location finally retrieved on the JavaScript side ? Do you face the issue if you directly pass the locations in javascript , i mean hard coded as a test ?

Comment: There are functions that are defined on the front end jsp file which communicate with the back end java server which retrieves the location coordinates from the database. I then use Here maps reverse geocoder and obtain the exact location which then populates the information for the marker and infobubble. It works when there is only one location in the database, but when there is two the map cant render the two markers with infobubles and I get that view when testing. I have updated my code above to include the onsuccess result.